# Inverse of a function $xe^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, inverse

How should I proceed about finding the inverse of the function $xe^x$? 
I have been wondering about it for a long time and can't think of anything to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of the function $f(x) = xe^{x}$ is called the Lambert W function.

Simply searching this function in Google should turn up some relevant videos / help.

Comment: why should $xe^{x}$ have an inverse function?

Comment: Whether the function $x\mathrm{e}^x$ should have a named inverse or not depends very much on how "useful" the inverse function turns out to be. In this particular case the inverse function, known as the Lambert W function, turns out to be very useful - something which only become apparent quite recently.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambert W function is the functional inverse of $xe^x = y$ and is defined as
$W(a)e^{W(a)} = a$
You can manipulate $xe^x = y$ algebraically to $0 = xe^x - y$
From there can find it using Newton's method $x_{n + 1} = x_n + \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

If you haven't learned calculus then know f'(x) is the DERIVATIVE of f(x) and look into how to find derivatives.

Fun tidbit W(1) = Ω = approx. 0.5671. This is called the OMEGA CONSTANT